# Response received from service to controller class is null after aspect gets executed on service class method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a controller class which further calls service class method. An AOP `@Around` aspect is applied on the service class method.

```java
package com.hetal.example;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustomerDetails() {
        System.out.println("Inside controller class");
        String details = customerService.getDetails(custName);
        System.out.println("Customer details is = " + details); // prints null
    }
}
```

```java
package com.hetal.example;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    @Override
    public String getDetails(String custName) {
        //some code
        returns "Customer details";
    }
}
```

An aspect is written to be executed `@Around` the method `getDetails()` of `CustomerServiceImpl`

```java
package com.hetal.config;

public class JoinPointConfig {
   @Pointcut(value="execution(* com.hetal.example.CustomerService.getDetails(..) && args(custName)")) 
   public void handleCustomerDetails(String custName) {}
}
```

```java
package com.hetal.config;

@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomerAspect {
   @Around("com.hetal.config.JoinPointConfig.handleCustomerDetails(custName)") 
   public Object aroundCustomerAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint, String custName) {
       System.out.println("Start aspect");
       Object result= null;
       try { 
          result = joinpoint.proceed();
          System.out.println("End aspect");
       }
       catch(Exception e) {}
    return result;
   }
}
```

Execution goes as below,

1. Controller calls `CustomerServiceImpl.getDetails` method.
2. `CustomerAspect` is called, prints "Start aspect". //before advice
3. `joinpoint.proceed()` calls actual `CustomerServiceImpl.getDetails` method.
4. `CustomerServiceImpl.getDetails` returns a string "Customer details" and control comes back to the aspect, prints "End aspect" //after returning advice
5. Control goes back to controller class but the response received is null.

I want the response returned from the service class into the controller class after the completion of the aspect.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Code you have shared doesn't compile.

Comment: Your intercepted method returns a `String` but your aspect returns nothing (`void`). Change the aspect's return type to `String` or `Object` and return the desired result, either the return value received by `proceed()` or whatever else is appropriate in your situation. Besides, the practice to swallow exceptions without handling or at least logging them is a horrible anti pattern. If the aspect cannot handle exceptions in a meaningful way, rather remove the try-catch altogether and just let the exception escalate.

Comment: I tried returning the result received by changing the return type but it did not work. @kriegaex

Comment: "Didn't work" does not qualify as a meaningful error description, I am afraid. If you have difficulty explaining better, maybe sharing a minimal version of your project reproducing the error on GitHub would be helpful.

Comment: @HetalRachh - try to log something in your aroundCustomerAdvice method's catch block - and share the results.

Comment: Yes it worked after returning the object received by proceed() method @kriegaex Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you some compilation issue in your applications make those changes and with the belwo return type issue in Aspect class, 
but the main issue is with your Aspect class, its void return type hence that coming as null you should return the result as object , below is the code

```
package com.hetal.config;
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class CustomerAspect {

       @Around("com.hetal.config.JoinPointConfig.handleCustomerDetails(custName)") 
       public Object aroundCustomerAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint, String custName) {
           System.out.println("Start aspect");

           Object result= null;
           try { 
              result = joinpoint.proceed();
              System.out.println("End aspect");
           }
           catch(Exception e) {}
 return result;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I tried returning the result received by changing the return type but it did not work.

Comment: I have tested the same code it worked for me you can test also, below is the git hub link https://github.com/panditb/stackdemos